# Discovering information about a Python Script Launched as a Service on Red Hat Linux

Tags: python, service, redhat, environment

I have a client who has an existing Red Hat Linux server setup on Amazon Web Services (AWS) where the important Python server code is launched as a service using `sudo service bigserver2 start`. When I try and run the bigserver2.py Python script independently, there are a number of runtime issues for paths and files not found. How can I backtrack through the service system and understand what environment the service is running in so I can replicate and debug some issues.

I can see the `bigserver2` service running when I run `sudo service --status-all` and it looks like they are initiating a command with some paths added, but I don't know where my predecessor (now gone and unavailable) set things up or what else may impact the environment.

```
root     14207     1  0 20:15 ?        00:00:00 sudo -u webuser LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/webusershared/python/ext PYTHONPATH=/opt/webusershared/python/ext/ /usr/bin/python3.6 /opt/webusershared/bigserver2.py
```

Comment: So there is no install or configuration help? If this has been built up, ad hoc, over time, then browsing the source is likely the best option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using service command instead of systemctl, I am guessing you are on REHL 6 (consider upgrading).

/etc/init.d/

Check this path, you will find a file with a name starting with "bigserver2".

Reference:
https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/deployment_guide/s1-services-running

Answer (score 1):

Assuming systemd, go look in `/lib/systemd/system` and `/etc/systemd/system` for a file that matches the service name.  Open that up and see what it's doing.  That's likely what the system is using to launch that service.